# how to delay a function works without a trigger (with document ready)

Tags: jquery, function, delay

i have this function that starts a slideshow automatically and i need to delay it till the server executes query and echo data

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
            height: '380px',
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true
        });

    });
```

i've tried this but didn't work

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(camera,2000);

    });
    $('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
            height: '380px',
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true
        });
```

Comment: More clarification is needed on what is the expected behavior.  Echo the data means server has to send response to an ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If with

> server executes query

you mean some ajax call then you need to use the callback and call your code there.

Otherwise, in the timeout example, you need to create a function named `camera` because that is what `setTimeout` expects

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(camera,2000);
});
function camera(){
    $('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
            height: '380px',
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is run the `.camera` method after a delay of 2 seconds, you can do that like this by putting the method into a function that `setTimeout()` will call after the prescribed delay:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
            height: '380px',
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true
        });
    },2000);
});
```

Usually a hard-coded wait time like this is the wrong solution.  The right solution is usually to wait for a particular event to occur and have a listener for that event.

I can't tell from your question (since you included no information on what the server response was that you are waiting for), but perhaps the event you want here is the response from an ajax call to the server.  If that is the case, then you can install a callback for the completion of that ajax call and run the `.camera()` method in that callback.

Comment: @jqbeginner - I'm curious why you selected the answer that creates an unnecessary global function `function camera() {}` vs. this one that uses an anonymous function and doesn't define any symbols in the global namespace?  In case you aren't aware, it's best to NOT define global symbols in javascript unless required as they are an opportunity to clash with other javascript on the page, whereas local functions or anonymous functions don't have that liability.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the delay() jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#camera_wrap_2').delay(2000).camera({
        height: '380px',
        loader: 'bar',
        pagination: false,
        thumbnails: true
    });

});
```

Comment: Unless the `.camera()` method is an animation and uses the animation queue, `.delay()` will NOT work here.  The `.camera()` method will not wait for the delay to happen.  `.delay()` only operates on methods that use the animation queue.

Comment: for me, a slideshow use animation, that's why I advise to use delay. No need to vote down for this... if you have no animation, use a basic setTimeout

Comment: @user1073122 - but the OP reports that this doesn't work and that's probably because the `.camera()` method itself is not an animation and that's why `.delay()` doesn't work with it.  I downvoted because the answer doesn't work.